The alignment of rep and badges is off on the top bar
I'm not sure if this has been raised elsewhere, but on the user awards in the top bar, the alignment of text for the reputation and badges is off, and it's a bit annoying:
 --> 
Meta Stack Exchange
You can see by highlighting the list container, the top of the rep number and the bottom of the badge container both appear to have a bit of extra padding. The misalignment is due to the container ul attempting to align its children to the center, and the child list items being slightly different sizes.
Potential fix
It can be fixed by changing the align-items prop on .s-user-card .s-user-card--awards from center to baseline, which will align them along the baseline of the text, rather than the center of the container:
 --> 

This bug appears to affect every site - I assume the top bar user awards widget is shared across all of them. I have tested Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange, Arqade, Role Playing Games, and Sustainability, and the fix is the same across all of them.


I'm on Firefox (Mac), at 100% zoom.
Info about baseline (Stack Overflow)

